# Триггер запускающий процедуру при условии

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Нужен триггер, запускающий процедуру при условии в Oracle.
Если столбец doc в таблице docs не пустой, то должна срабатывать процедура v2020_2.

Структура таблицы

```
  create table DOCS
(
  DOC CLOB
)
```

Процедура

```
create or replace procedure v2020_2 is
. . .
end v2020_2;
```

Comment: Не совсем понятна задача. Зачем в триггере запускать процедуру? А просто после вставки её нельзя запустить?

Comment: select * from docs t - это не таблица. это запрос, который не может дать информацию о структуре таблицы, а этого не хватает в вопросе.

Comment: Как только в clob к поступят данные, то срабатывает процедура. Процедура из clob разбивает и конвертирует данные в другую таблицу в нужном формате.

Comment: _в clob поступят данные_, откуда, как и в каком кол-ве они поступят? На первый комментарий вы не ответили, почему нужен иммено триггер?

Comment: Данные к примеру будут внесены. В количестве более 4000 символов. Необязательно триггер, можно и job ...

Comment: _В количестве более 4000 символов_, это не колличество, это размер. Данные могут быть  записаны в таблицу через одиночный insert, а могут быть загружены массово, например, из миллионов "подвезённых с утра" файлов с помощью sqlldr.

Answer (score 3):

Нужен ли триггер в этом случае. Если похожего обоснования нет в [Reasons to Use Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-C08EA160-8FD2-4A10-9733-6F2D20C83E93), то причина очень часто - скрыть код от коллег, чтобы они его не сразу нашли.

Далее, следует учесть, что "пустой" и `NULL` (неопределён), это не одно и тоже.

Посмотрите, как всё красиво получается, приняв во внимание выше изложенное:

```
create table docs (
    id int generated by default on null as identity, 
    name varchar2 (16), doc clob, len number, status varchar2 (12))
/
create or replace package docpack as  
    procedure new (name varchar2, doc clob := empty_clob ());
    procedure process (id number, doc clob);
end;
/
create or replace package body docpack as  
    procedure new (name varchar2, doc clob := empty_clob ()) as
        id number;
    begin 
        insert into docs values (null, name, doc, length (doc), 'new')
        returning id into id;
        if doc != empty_clob () then process (id, doc); end if;
    end;
    procedure process (id number, doc clob) is 
    begin 
        /* do something */
        update docs set status = 'processed'
        where id = process.id;
    end;
end;
/
```

И использовать не сложно:

```
exec - 
    docpack.new ('1st doc'); - 
    docpack.new ('2nd doc', 'abc 123'); 

select * from docs;

        ID NAME             DOC             LEN STATUS      
---------- ---------------- -------- ---------- ------------
         1 1st doc                            0 new         
         2 2nd doc          abc 123           7 processed
```

Comment: Можно пояснить поподробнее что вы демонстрируете.

Comment: Как только в таблице docs в колонку doc поступят данные, и если doc не пустой, будет запущенна процедура, которая doc обработает. Если что-то в коде не понятно, то спрашивайте.

Answer (score 0):

примерно так

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME
    AFTER INSERT
    ON docs
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.doc IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN   
    EXECUTE v2020_2;
END;
```

или

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME
    AFTER INSERT
    ON docs
    FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN   
    IF :NEW.doc IS NOT NULL then
    EXECUTE v2020_2;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Error: PLS-00103: Встретился символ "V2020_2" в то время как ожидалось одно из следующих:
       
          := . ( @ % ; immediate
       Символ ":=" заменен на "V2020_2", чтобы можно было продолжать.

Comment: я же указал что это примерно. Как называется ваша хранимка и в какой она схеме проверяйте сами

Comment: С EXECUTE Error: PLS-00103, без него ошибка исчезает, но Процедура не срабатывает.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 0):

Job решил мою задачу, причем использовал сразу две процедуры, одна за другой.  Сначала выполняется первая процедура и следом вторая.

```
begin
  sys.dbms_job.submit(job => :job,
                      what => 'begin
  -- Call the procedure
  v2020_22;
end;

begin
  -- Call the procedure
  v2020_2;
end;',
                      next_date => to_date('01-01-4000', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
                      interval => '(sysdate)+2/1440');
  commit;
end;
```

Comment: Очень странное решение. Пакет dbms_job устарел, больше не рекомендован к применению и обычно его отключают. Ничего общего с вашим вопросом это решение не имеет. Скорее всего вы не совсем поняли вашу задачу и не смогли грамотно сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Я с вами согласен. Триггер не смог запустить процедуру.

Comment: _Триггер не смог запустить процедуру_, смог бы, если его правильно написать, но он не нужен (почему, написано в моём ответе). Проблема в вопросе не только триггер. Всё, что там описано, полностью не соответствует тому, что теперь предложено в вашем ответе.  Почему решение в вашем ответе решило задачу, непонятно?

Comment: Автоматизировать процедуру. Триггер и джоб это сделать могут. Что тогда еще можно сделать для автоматизации процедуры?

Comment: А что такое - _Автоматизировать процедуру_? Пока не станет понятно, что вы пытаетесь достичь, я ничего не смогу предложить.

Comment: _Триггер и джоб это сделать могут_ , между ними только одна разница, триггер выполнит в текущей сессии, job - в другой сесии. Зачем вам нужна другая сессия?  А просто выполнить процедуру, почему вы вообще не рассмтриваете такой вариант?

Comment: К примеру вставляем в таблицу данные. И чтобы процедура автоматически срабатывала, выполняла действия. Цель такая, как только в clob попадают(загружаются) данные в виде xml то процедурой все как нужно конвертируется и идет распределение по нужным таблицам.

Comment: Ну хорошо, я же предложил ответ, он делает точь в точь, то что вы описали в последнем комментарии. И даже показал как это работает в полностью воспроизводимом примере.

Comment: Получается как в docs прилетают данные то автоматически срабатывает package в котором прописана процедура?
Т.е. ничего запускать не нужно дополнительно.

Comment: _Получается как в docs прилетают данные_, а откуда это они прилетают? Вы не знаете откуда у вас данные в таблице появляются?

Comment: _то автоматически срабатывает package_, нет, процедуру из пакета надо запускать вместо вставки новых документов. Если действительно не известно, где это вставка происходит, то надо это узнать, без  этого нельзя найти оптимальное решение.

Comment: Если имеется ввиду вставка - то это данные xml(т.е. код xml) который будет попадать в таблицу где есть clob. Xml будет загружаться вручную, ну и потом должны выполняться процедуры. А по загрузке xml выдала у меня 403 ошибку о которую я опубликовал.

Comment: А  это что - _Xml будет загружаться вручную_? Что значить "вручную"? Любые данные могут попасть в таблицу, только если будет выполнен insert. Описание того, где и как этот insert будет запущен, напрмер: "вручную", "выстрелом из рогатки", не совсем удачные.